# Local Server: Cannot change existing images HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html, apache2, updates

I converted a static HTML+CSS+JS website to php, only header and footer were separated, in header.php and footer.php.rest of the pages were changed from .html to .php, but when I am adding a new image and replacing it with an existing image, the image is not showing. If I replace the existing image with an image that I already had in the folder it will work but if I add a new image it won't work.
I am using apache2 local server.
I have tried clearing browser cache and also restarted the server but nothing changes.

1. the browser console shows GET http://example.com/images/logo.png 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Please show the code, also check the network tab of your developer console. That should show you how the image is being called.

Comment: @user3783243 I did not use any php code I just took the header part and pasted it into header.php and used <?php 

include('template/layout/header.php');

?>

Comment: the browser console says file not found

Comment: What is the path it is requesting and what is its actual path?

Comment: it is requesting /images/logo.png and it is the actual path

Comment: Is the site accessible globally?

Comment: I made a change and now console shows 403 forbidden

Comment: Okay... you're not giving us much to work with here.

Comment: I don't know about global access but I can access it with any browser

Comment: File permissions?